# VBA Macro to Copy and paste in interval of 12 rows

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I need to copy a range of cells (A10:Z25)
and then to paste it 12 rows under last row or range, row Z.
This need to take place 1000 times.

In other words: 
Copy 16 rows
Jump 12 rows (from the last cell of the range)
paste the 16 rows
jump 12 rows (from the last cell of the range)
paste 16 rows

and so on.. 1000 times.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). You might also want to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Magical Mystery Tour") and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim intRowno As Integer

intRowno = 1

For i = 1 To 1000

    Range("A10:Z25").Copy Cells(intRowno, 2)
    intRowno = ((i + i) * 12) + 1

Next


End Sub
```